# issue with rails composite_primary_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, undefined-behavior, composite-primary-key, flatten, fixnum

I'm trying to create a composite primary key using rails and postgresql. I've clearly followed the instruction in the documentation for the gem composite_primary_keys.

When I execute "puts modelname.primary_keys", I'm getting the columns that I created composite primary keys for.

But the problem is, when I try to insert data into the model by giving following commands:

```
m = classname.new
m.id = 10   # One of the columns in composite primary key
m.another_table_id = 5 # the second column in composite primary key
m.name = "Test"
m.save

I'm getting "undefined method 'flatten!' for 1:Fixnum
path/composite_primary_keys/base.rb:134in 'id=' "
```

So please suggest me what's going wrong. Or please get me a link to sample project using composite_pirmary_keys.

Thanks in advance.
Senthil.

Comment: Composite primary keys are against the Convention over Configuration principal of Rails. You can get into many problems with finders, relationships, etc. If it's a question of uniqueness, you'd better use validation and an index in your DB to ensure speed.

Comment: Did you do something like this in your model: self.primary_keys

Comment: No. I just have set_primary_keys :id, :another_tabe_id

Comment: Then you need to go back and read the documentation on how to use this gem. The docs clearly state: # self.primary_keys *keys - turns on composite key functionality. You will find it here: http://compositekeys.rubyforge.org/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But using self.primary_keys :id, :another_table_id results in undefined method primary_keys' for #<Class:0x8f22698>